# How to hide div that without id/class by jquery?

Tags: jquery, hide

How to hide first/second div with jQuery?

Div can not get id/class!

```
<body>
<div>
<p>ssssssss</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>ttttttttt></p>
</div>
<div>
<p>fffff</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To hide the first `<div>` element, do:

```
$("div:eq(0)").hide();
```

To hide the second `<div>` element, do:

```
$("div:eq(1)").hide();
```

To hide both the first and the second `<div>` elements, do:

```
$("div:lt(2)").hide();
```

Comment: NOTE: this doesn't work with the firebug console open! (the first div is div#_firebugConsole)

Comment: @Emmett, good point, use `$("div:not(#_firebugConsole):eq(0)")` then :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div:lt(2)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("body div:nth-child(1)").hide();` perhaps?  untested

HTML markup is needed to help further

**edit** - ah ha, code block fail - my code still stands but i suspect there's a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-selectors :first and :nth(n)... Note that nth(n) is zero-based. So :nth(0) is equivalent to :first.

```
$('div:first').hide();
$('div:nth(1)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide child div 1 and child div 2 (or 3 or 4)

```
   $('body div:nth-child(1),body div:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

nth-child is the offset and the comma seperates out which ones.. in case you wanted to keep div# 2 it could be

```
 $('body div:nth-child(1),body div:nth-child(3)').hide();
```